# excel vba Parse the filename as a string when using the getopenfilename method

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below to select an `xlsx` file to copy 2 selected `worksheets` from an `active workbook` to an existing workbook.  What I want to do is keep the filename as a string so that I can late close the workbook I copy to.  Trouble is the string  or variant value isn't retained.

```
Dim NwWbk As Workbook

Set NwWbk = Workbooks.Open(Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xls; *.xlsm),*.xls;*.xslm", Title:="Select file to sheets into."))

Workbook(nwwbk).close
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a reference to the `Workbook` object in the variable `NwWbk`, you dont need to keep the name in another variable (which you could do as well). You can access all about its name by

`NwWbk.Name`, `NwWbk.FullName`, `NwWbk.Path` etc.

You can also close it by

```
NwWbk.Close`
```

However, the problem in your code is that if the user presses `Cancel` in the file dialog, you will be trying to open a `False` workbook which results in a runtime error. The correct way is the get the user's selection and *check* if the selection was cancelled. (Notice also some correction of the `Filefilter` parameter of your initital code):

```
Dim NwWbk As Workbook, wbName as string
wbName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Workbooks (*.xls; *.xlsm),*.xls;*.xslm", Title:="Select file to sheets into.")

If wbName = "False" then
    ' User pressed Cancel. Deal with this case
    ' ...
Else
    Set NwWbk = Workbooks.Open(wbName)
    ' Process the opened workbook
    ' ...
    NwWbk .close
End If
```